# ¿ Donde se alojan las constantes?

Tags: c

Bueno, según he leído el compilador podría ubicarlos en la pila o en un área de memoria de solo lectura, el estándar no garantiza que sea lo primero o lo segundo.

Según el estándar cualquier intento de modificar una variable tipo constante es comportamiento indefinido.

¿Que pasa si el compilador decide colocar esta variable en la pila el estándar sigue firme en este caso?

Comment: hola, podrias agregar la fuente donde  leiste lo de la pila?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945640/why-can-i-change-a-local-const-variable-through-pointer-casts-but-not-a-global-o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Caso 1**: La constante acaba en una región de solo lectura

Quien controla que esa región de memoria sea de solo lectura es el Sistema Operativo... al detectar un intento de escritura lo normal es que el SO mate la aplicación que está intentando escribir para proteger la integridad de la memoria.

**Caso 2**: La constante acaba en la pila

La pila es una región de memoria que admite operaciones de lectura y escritura. En este caso la única protección de que el valor sea constante la ofrece el compilador y, dicho sea de paso, es una protección bastante endeble. Lo esperable en estos casos es que el valor de la constante pueda verse modificado en tiempo de ejecución sin problemas.

El estándar indica que el resultado de modificar una constante es indeterminado se debe a la existencia del primer caso. Dado que este comportamiento depende de la pareja compilador-SO es imposible dar una respuesta uniforme.

Comment: Sip, lo más probable es que te toque un `SIGSEGV` por estar andando donde no debes

Answer (score 0):

No pierdas nunca de vista que C es un lenguaje **portable**; se espera de él que compile para diversos Sistemas Operativos y Arquitecturas, con cambios mínimos (o nulos).

¿ Que pasa si compilas un código que hace uso de `const` para una arquitectura que no soporta protección de memoria ? Cualquier *micro-controlador* entra dentro de esta categoría. O el *vetusto* *MSDOS*.

Aunque es posible controlar esta circunstancia mediante el uso de *macros* del pre-procesador, el lenguaje, *en si mismo*, no tiene forma de controlar esto. Es imposible controlar *donde* acabará una variable. **Ni siquiera puedes estar seguro** de que las variables *automáticas* acabaran en la pila, por el sencillo hecho de que C **no tiene el concepto de *pila***: solo tienes el concepto de **tiempo de vida mínimo** de una variable. Lo que tu crees que está en la pila, puede terminar en cualquier parte: **depende de la arquitectura**. ¿ Porqué si no tendriamos `<stdarg.h>` ? Por eso mismo, para *abstraer* el concepto de *paso-de-parámetros*.

Es por todo lo anterior que la modificación de variables `const` genera un **comportamiento indefinido**: puede que una arquitectura lo permita; puede que un Sistema Operativo no. Puede que se genere un error de acceso a memoria. O puede que [demonios salgan de tus fosas nasales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).